# Service Bus Namespace and Topic with a Subscription using a SQL Filter

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-servicebus-topics

I was trying to deploy as Service Bus Namespace and Topic with a Subscription using a SQL Filter with this example [Service Bus Topic Subscription SqlFilter template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-servicebus-topic-subscription-sqlfilter), I get the Namespace, the Topic, the Subscription and the SQL Filter created well, but the condition of the SQL Filter is the default (1=1), not the condition that I added on my template (ex: [property-name] = 'value').

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you referenced this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693927/azure-service-bus-filter-not-applied-when-defined-in-arm-template)?  More details info, you also could refer to [Create a Service Bus namespace with topic, subscription, and rule using an Azure Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-topic-with-rule#what-are-rules-filters).

Comment: Thank you so much @TomSun, with "sqlFilter" instead of "filter", it works, but then the Microsoft documentation is wrong?